# dotnet ef failed to run when dotnet is installed manually using binary package

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I am installing dotnet manually by downloading the binary files and extract it in some directory. I have exported the path and it works.

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.401
 Commit:    0906eae6f8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  12.6
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.12-arm64
 Base Path:   /opt/homebrew/opt/dotnet@6/sdk/6.0.401/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.9
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       163a63591c

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.401 [/opt/homebrew/opt/dotnet@6/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/opt/homebrew/opt/dotnet@6/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/opt/homebrew/opt/dotnet@6/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

I have installed the dotnet EF tools and it can installed successfully but when I run the dotnet ef command, I got this error:

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/bkalbuaji/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: arm64
App host version: 6.0.9
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64&apphost_version=6.0.9
```

It seems it doesn't recognize the dotnet although I can install it using dotnet tool install command.

It is really weird. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Im having the same problem, did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Was this fixed? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Glubus were you able to make it work?

Comment: no, I install dotnet using installer to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following line to my `.bash_profile`:
`export PATH="$PATH:/home/<MY-USER-NAME>/.dotnet/tools"` which is the directory `dotnet` installed `dotnet-ef`.

For Windows, the equivalent solution would be to add the directory where the `dotnet-ef` program is installed, to your PATH env variable.

I think the issue was that `dotnet ef` just runs `dotnet-ef` and expects it's exposed by the PATH var, but in my case it was not somehow.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I remember trying this and it was not working. When I have multiple .NET version installed, the tools folder contain all of tools from different version and it messed everything.